# Using .filter and .collect on small practice RDD to print all words beginning with 'h' (pyspark beginner)

Tags: python, pyspark, lambda, jupyter-notebook, rdd

I'm just starting to learn how to use pyspark on Jupyternotebook and a beginner coder.

To test the waters I created this array:
word = ['hey', 'how', 'are', 'you']

Then this RDD:
wordRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([word])

I am now trying to use .filter and .collect on wordRDD to print all words beginning with 'h' but just can't reach the solution. Does anyone have any ideas?

This is as far as I have got:

```py
word = ['hey', 'how', 'are', 'you']
wordRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([word])

print(wordRDD.filter.map(lambda x=x: x in wordRDD if x[0] == "h").collect())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, the function call is [RDD.filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.filter.html):

```py
words = ['hey', 'how', 'are', 'you']
wordRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(words)

filterRDD = wordRDD.filter(lambda word: word.startswith("h"))
print(filterRDD.collect())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Kafels!!

Comment: I'm getting this as the response: list object has no attribute 'startswith' - should i convert to string?

Comment: It depends, your RDD should be a list of lists or list of strings?

Comment: it's a list of strings

Comment: I have updated my answer, you must remove these brackets `spark.sparkContext.parallelize([words])`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help!!!!